# different behavior for different "for"s in benchmark

Tags: c++, for-loop, google-benchmark

We can write a simple benchmark using [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) or https://www.quick-bench.com/,

```
static void range_based_for(benchmark::State &state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::to_string(__LINE__);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(range_based_for);
```

We can also rewrite it with std::for_each,

```
static void std_for_each(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::for_each (std::begin(state), std::end(state), [] (auto _) {
        std::to_string(__LINE__);
    });
}
BENCHMARK(std_for_each);
```

Everything is good.
However, when we use old school for statement, it runs without finishing.

```
static void old_school_for(benchmark::State &state) {
    for (auto iter = std::begin(state); iter != std::end(state); ++iter) {
        std::to_string(__LINE__);
    };
}
BENCHMARK(old_school_for);
```

In fact, std::for_each is implemented with this style. How can they behave different?

Comment: First of all, do you build with optimization enabled? Benchmarking should always be done on optimized builds. And if you build with optimizations, then the loops would probably be no-ops, and do nothing since they have no side-effects.

Comment: As for the problem with the third loop, look at the generated assembly code to try and figure out the problem. Use e.g. [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) to help you.

Comment: One difference between those "styles" is how many times `std::end(state)` is executed. Try caching that value in the last snippet.

Comment: Not only `std::for_each` is implemented that way – the range based for loop maps to something pretty similar as well, though some details differ, e.g. the range-based for loop is mandated by the standard to operate such that `begin` and `end` getting called just once (if I recall correctly) – compare Bob's comment.

Comment: One difference is that the last loop calls `std::end(state)` on every iteration, but the other two do not (a range-based `for` is specified accordingly, and the arguments of `std::for_each()` are evaluated before it is called  - so `std::end(state)` is not reevaluated on each iteration).    If `std::end(state)` affects members of `state` on each call [I don't know, not having read documentation or source for `benchmark::State`] that might explain the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `begin`/`end` functions are documented with [a warning](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/include/benchmark/benchmark.h#L609): says "These functions should not be called directly"

> These functions should not be called directly.
>
> REQUIRES: The benchmark has not started running yet. Neither begin nor end have been called previously.

[`end` calls `StartKeepRunning`](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/include/benchmark/benchmark.h#L921)

And what does `StartKeepRunning` do? [It resets the number of iterations to the maximum](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/src/benchmark.cc#L235)

It is clear that you're only supposed to call `begin` and `end` once. The difference in your third loop is that `std::end(state)` is called once per iteration, which apparently resets the iteration count back to the maximum.

I have no idea why the library is designed this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I precompute end instead of call end() and it runs as expected.

Comment: i'm the author of the library. can you explain why this is preferred to the documented first loop version? i'd like to know if i should support this use-case better.

Comment: dma you need to ping @luckycpp to ask why s/he is doing this

Comment: I was trying to replace range-based-for with tbb::parallel_for_each, and incidentally tried those other two ways.